# How to sync between client timings and server timings in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

I've some logs in my website, If I host the website on my localhost it is showing my local time, but if I host the same codes on my server and even though I set my default timezone using `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');` the logs are using different timings. I'm using `Linux server` How can I sync between these two timings.

Comment: Store all dates as UTC? You have not indicated any technology or shown any code, that makes it hard to offer any other advice. What technology is this? What server is this? How are you setting the default timezone (is it for the right user?)

Comment: @DaveShaw `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');` this is how I set my default timezone.

Comment: Cheers, I've tried to incorporate that into your question. Most people do use UTC for all their timings as you often have no control over the servers where it is deployed.